# CloudKit: Fetch all records with a certain record type?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, ckrecord

I have currently got **CloudKit** set up in my app so that I am adding a new record using the help of the following code below,

```
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"stringArray"];
CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Strings" recordID:recordID];
[record setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil] forKey:@"stringArray"];
[_privateDatabase saveRecord:record completionHandler:nil];
```

However, now I would like to be able to fetch ALL records that are of the same record type, "Strings," and return those compiled into an NSArray. How would I go about doing that? Currently, all I have figured out is how to fetch each record individually, using a recordID, which is a hassle, there must be an easier way.

```
[_privateDatabase fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
   if (error) {
      // Error handling for failed fetch from private database
   }
   else {
      NSLog(@"ICLOUD TEST: %@", [record objectForKey:@"stringArray"]);            
  }
}];
```

Comment: According to CKQuery API Reference: "Predicates are based on a format string. You cannot use value or block-based predicates." I don't think it was always like this, but currently neither answer would be correct because they use `NSPredicate(value:)`

Comment: I have used it in the past, but anyone doing so should know that it's not supported for CloudKit, according to Apple's own documentation. Apple could very well make changes that would break that code, and it can be done w/out using value or block based predicates.

Comment: I'd argue that it's akin to identifying enums through hash-values. You can get away with it, until the declaration order changes and your code breaks...essentially, there's a reason why manufacturers include manuals for how to use their api's, etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aaaand, I've got it. Using the code below, I was able to create a query to run on the database, to then return an NSArray in the completion block, which I looped through, and returned the value for the saved key in an NSLog.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Strings" predicate:predicate];

[_privateDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    for (CKRecord *record in results) {
        NSLog(@"Contents: %@", [record objectForKey:@"stringArray"]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: this won't return all records though, just a subset (usually limited to 100 by default)

Comment: @MaxDesiatov what you mean with limited? How to fetch all?

Comment: Never mind, it (100 limit) is answered here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592964/ckquery-from-private-zone-returns-only-first-100-ckrecords-from-in-cloudkit) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728115/limit-the-amount-of-results-returned-in-cloudkit)

Comment: Does not work. Getting error: <CKError 0x13de5ffc0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2015); server message = "Field '___recordID' is not marked queryable"

Answer (score 8):

Solution for **Swift 4**, 
shows how to fetch all the records of type "YourTable", also prints `System Field` and `Custom Field`:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "YourTable", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
  records?.forEach({ (record) in

    // System Field from property
    let recordName_fromProperty = record.recordID.recordName
    print("System Field, recordName: \(recordName_fromProperty)")

    // Custom Field from key path (eg: deeplink)
    let deeplink = record.value(forKey: "deeplink")
    print("Custom Field, deeplink: \(deeplink ?? "")")
  })
}
```

Comment: this query does not fetch more objects than 100 at a time

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

After looking through a bunch of posts and solutions on SO I have managed to come with a solution that suits my needs and should be simple enough for anyone that just wants to fetch all of their records of given type from iCloud.

#### Solution

The solution that uses an extension to the CKDatabase to introduce a method that handles the `cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor` of `CKQueryOperation` to continue asking iCloud for more records. In this approach I dispatch to the background queue so I can block it and wait for the operation to be finished completely, either on receiving an error or with the last batch of records. Once the semaphore unlocks the queue it proceeds with calling the main completion block with the result. Also I am taking advantage of Swift's `Result` type in the completion handler.

```swift
extension CKDatabase {

    func fetchAll(
        recordType: String, resultsLimit: Int = 100, timeout: TimeInterval = 60,
        completion: @escaping (Result<[CKRecord], Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [unowned self] in
            let query = CKQuery(
                recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true)
            )
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            var records = [CKRecord]()
            var error: Error?

            var operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
            operation.resultsLimit = resultsLimit
            operation.recordFetchedBlock = { records.append($0) }
            operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, err) in
                guard err == nil, let cursor = cursor else {
                    error = err
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return
                }
                let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
                newOperation.resultsLimit = operation.resultsLimit
                newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = operation.recordFetchedBlock
                newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
                operation = newOperation
                self?.add(newOperation)
            }
            self?.add(operation)

            _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + 60)

            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                completion(.success(records))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### Usage

Using the method is fairly straight forward for anyone familiar with Swift's closure syntax and `Result` type.

```swift
let database: CKDatabase = ...
database.fetchAll(recordType: "User") { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let users):
            // Handle fetched users, ex. save them to the database
        case .failure(let error):
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your add function?  Thanks.

Comment: @Emmy I am calling `add(_ operation: CKDatabaseOperation)` method on `CKDatabase`

Comment: Why is self optional? Is this something that changed in later Swift versions? Xcode makes me take it out.

Comment: @WitekBobrowski do you have an updated version? This code fails with error "Cannot convert value of type 'CKRecord.ID' to expected argument type 'CKRecord'" and "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" after correcting deprecated items.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an updated version since our CloudKit sync now leverages the change token instead of fetching the records directly. When I have time I will update the answer with new API.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer in Swift 3.0.

```
func myQuery()  {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "tableName", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (record, error) in

        for record: CKRecord in record! {
            //...

            // if you want to access a certain 'field'.
            let name = record.value(forKeyPath: "Name") as! String                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The followig function will return ALL records for requested record type:

```
let database = CKContainer(identifier: "container_here").privateCloudDatabase
typealias RecordsErrorHandler = ([CKRecord], Swift.Error?) -> Void

func fetchRecords(forType type: String, completion: RecordsErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var records = [CKRecord]()

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: type, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.zoneID = CloudAssistant.shared.zone.zoneID

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
        records.append(record)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in

        self.fetchRecords(with: cursor, error: error, records: records) { records in
            completion?(records, nil)
        }
    }

    database.add(queryOperation)
}

private func fetchRecords(with cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: Swift.Error?, records: [CKRecord], completion: RecordsHandler?) {

    var currentRecords = records

    if let cursor = cursor, error == nil {

        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)

        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            currentRecords.append(record)
        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            self.fetchRecords(with: cursor, error: error, records: currentRecords, completion: completion)
        }

        database.add(queryOperation)

    } else {
        completion?(records)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In trying to fetch all records, and understand the structure and details of Cloudkit storage, I found it useful to have the following function available during debug. This uses semaphores to retain the data structure for printing. There may be a more elegant way to do this but this works!

```
//
// Print a list of records in all zones in all databases
//
func printRecordsInContainers() {

    let myContainer = CKContainer.default()
    // Edit the following dictionary to include any known containers and possible record types
    let containerRecordTypes: [CKContainer: [String]] = [ myContainer: ["MyRecordType", "OldRecordType", "MyUser", "PrivateInfo"] ]
    let containers = Array(containerRecordTypes.keys)

    for containerz in containers {
        let databases: [CKDatabase] = [containerz.publicCloudDatabase, containerz.privateCloudDatabase, containerz.sharedCloudDatabase]

        for database in databases {
            var dbType = "<None>"
            if database.databaseScope.rawValue == 1 { dbType = "Public" }
            if database.databaseScope.rawValue == 2 { dbType = "Private" }
            if database.databaseScope.rawValue == 3 { dbType = "Shared" }

            //print("\(database.debugDescription)")
            print("\n\n\n ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print(" ----- Container: \(containerz.containerIdentifier ?? "??") ----- Database: \(dbType)")
            let semaphore1 = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)     // Initiate semaphore1 to wait for closure to return

            database.fetchAllRecordZones { zones, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(" Error Fetching Zones: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                else if let zones = zones {
                    print("~~~~ \(zones.count) : \(zones)")
                    for zone in zones {
                        print("----- Zone ID: \(zone.zoneID)\n")
                        for recordType in containerRecordTypes[container] ?? [] {
                            print("[  Record Type: \(recordType.description)  ]")
                            let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))

                            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)     // Initiate semaphore to wait for closure to return
                            database.perform(query, inZoneWith: zone.zoneID) { records, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print(" Error in Record Query: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                                else if let records = records {
                                    printRecordDescriptions(records)
                                }
                                semaphore.signal()      // Send semaphore signal to indicate closure is complete
                            }
                            semaphore.wait()            // Wait for semaphore to indicate that closure is complete
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print(" Error in fetchAllRecordZones")
                }
                semaphore1.signal()      // Send semaphore1 signal to indicate closure is complete
            }
            semaphore1.wait()            // Wait for semaphore1 to indicate that closure is complete
        }
    }
}
class func printRecordDescriptions(_ records: [CKRecord]) {
    print("Records and Contents List:")
    for record in records {
        print(" Record: \(record.recordID)")
        for key in record.allKeys() {
            print("    Key - \(key)")
        }
    }
    print("Record List End\n")
}
```

Comment: Would this have an issue w/ the number of records being fetched? I read that default is only return 100 records

Comment: This would only return 100 records (per the default) since it doesn't use a cursor