# Fetching all records from CloudKit using cursor recursive function - how to pass the result outside of its scope?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, cloudkit

This may be tricky question so maybe someone here can help unless what I'm trying to do is forbidden by design.

So, I am fetching all the cloudkit records in packs to avoid 400 records limit. My function is:

```
func ck_queryAllStations(in_private:Bool) -> [CKRecord] {

        var records = [CKRecord]()
        let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType:"RadioStation", predicate: pred)
        let pDatabase:CKDatabase

      if in_private == true {
            pDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    } else {
            pDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        }

        let queryOperation =  CKQueryOperation(query: query)

        queryOperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            records.append(record)
            print("rekord dopisany do tablicy\n")


        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor,error in

            if cursor != nil {
                print("Jest Wiecej danych do pobrania - \(String(describing: cursor))")
                self.fetchRecordsCloudKit(cursor: cursor!,in_private: in_private)
            } else {
//                print(self.records)
            }

        }

        pDatabase.add(queryOperation)
        return records
    }
```

However,to achieve this I must use helper recursive function that is defined as below:

```
func fetchRecordsCloudKit(cursor:CKQueryOperation.Cursor?,in_private:Bool)  {

        print("Funkcja fetchRecordsCloudKit uruchomiona\n")
        let pDatabase:CKDatabase
        if in_private == true {
                pDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
        } else {
                pDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            }

        let queryoperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
//        queryoperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
        queryoperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            records.append(record) // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
            print("rekord dopisany do tablicy")

        }
        queryoperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor,error in

                   if cursor != nil {
                       print("Wiecej danych do pobrania")
                    print(cursor as Any)

                       self.fetchRecordsCloudKit(cursor: cursor!,in_private: in_private)
                   }
               }
        pDatabase.add(queryoperation)

    }
```

Problem is `self.fetchRecordsCloudKit(cursor: cursor!,in_private: in_private)` does not know anything about `var records = [CKRecord]()` variable.

1. If function is launch inside function, shouldn't it have access to all its variables the same way as class' method have acces to all class global variables?
2. I tried to pass `records` variable to recursive function as inout parameter, but apparently inout parameters in closures are forbidden since Swift 3.

So what to do? Is the only solution moving `records` array outside anything? In my mind that looks dirty hack to make array available globally BEFORE each asynchronous operation finish.

Comment: That is the way to do it. I make a class for each model and make the records array a class variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CloudKit: Fetch all records with a certain record type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402846/cloudkit-fetch-all-records-with-a-certain-record-type)

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate, I have provided a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226852/8160613