# CKQuery from private zone returns only first 100 CKRecords from in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

Is there any limit to the result of a query to **Cloudkit** private default zone? I have no clue why I only receive first 100 records with the following query:

```
let p = NSPredicate(format: "(type == 'entered') AND (timestamp >= %@) AND (timestamp <= %@)", from, to)
let q = CKQuery(recordType: self.beaconRecordType, predicate: p)
q.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
self.privateDatabase?.performQuery(q, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { results, error in

    //count = 100
    println(results.count)

}
```

---

Okay. As Edwin mention in the answer, the solution is to use CKQueryOperation to fetch the initial block of data then use the "cursor" in completionBlock to fire another operation. Here is an example:

**UPDATE**

```
func fetchBeacons(from:NSDate, to:NSDate) {

    let p = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let q = CKQuery(recordType: self.beaconRecordType, predicate: p)

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: q)

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = fetchedARecord

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (cursor : CKQueryCursor!, error : NSError!) in

        if cursor != nil {
            println("there is more data to fetch")
            let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = self!.fetchedARecord
            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock
            self!.privateDatabase?.addOperation(newOperation)
        }

    }

    privateDatabase?.addOperation(queryOperation)
}

var i = 0
func fetchedARecord (record: CKRecord!) {
    println("\(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate*1000) \(++i)")
}
```

Comment: ok. I found this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27135836/893771 . A piece of code would help a lot though.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27728609/1966109) to a similar question also shows how to keep a strong reference to `queryOperation` in order to prevent your fetch to end while incomplete.

Comment: this solution will cause the operation to run only 3 times!, use this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31664231/530884

Answer (score 9, accepted):

100 is the default limit for standard queries. That amount is not fixed. It can vary depending on the total iCloud load. If you want to influence that amount, then you need to use CKQueryOperation and set the resultsLimit like this:
        operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults;
That CKQueryOperationMaximumResults is the default and will limit it to 100 (most of the time). Don't set that value too high. If you want more records, then use the cursor of the queryCompletionBlock to continue reading more records.

Comment: Great Edwin. I linked to you answer previously :). Do you have any example  code how to do 'cursor'? That would save some time for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a nice sample ready for that. But it's not dificult. You can just start a new queryOperation like this:  var operation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)

Comment: I accepted your answer and updated my question with example code. Tnx dude.

Comment: Great, but is there an example of this in Objective C?

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion @EdwinVermeer and providing the sample code @CPPChase! For the line "newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock" it doesn't feel like the right way to do it though, but I can't find a better approach - thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I have updated GuiSoySauce's code in Swift 4.2.

```
func cloudKitLoadRecords(result: @escaping (_ objects: [CKRecord]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    // predicate
    var predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    // query
    let cloudKitQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "recordType", predicate: predicate)

    // records to store
    var records = [CKRecord]()

    //operation basis
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    // recurrent operations function
    var recurrentOperationsCounter = 101
    func recurrentOperations(cursor: CKQueryCursor?){
        let recurrentOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
        recurrentOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
            print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - fetch \(recurrentOperationsCounter)")
            recurrentOperationsCounter += 1
            records.append(record)
        }
        recurrentOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - error - \(String(describing: error))")
                result(nil, error)
            } else {
                if cursor != nil {
                    print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - records \(records.count) - cursor \(cursor!.description)")
                    recurrentOperations(cursor: cursor!)
                } else {
                    print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - records \(records.count) - cursor nil - done")
                    result(records, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        publicDatabase.add(recurrentOperation)
    }
    // initial operation
    var initialOperationCounter = 1
    let initialOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: cloudKitQuery)
    initialOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - fetch \(initialOperationCounter)")
        initialOperationCounter += 1
        records.append(record)
    }
    initialOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - error - \(String(describing: error))")
            result(nil, error)
        } else {
            if cursor != nil {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - records \(records.count) - cursor \(cursor!.description)")
                recurrentOperations(cursor: cursor!)
            } else {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - records \(records.count) - cursor nil - done")
                result(records, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    publicDatabase.add(initialOperation)
}
```

Usage

```
cloudKitLoadRecords() { (records, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        // do something
    } else {
        if let records = records {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem was that I was assigning the `recurrentOperation` completion block to the same as the original completion block and the new completion block would never get called. Giving the `recurrentOperation` completion its own completion block fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for my project to fetch all record from a record type, it's in objective c. I use "Entry" as desiredKeys.

```
+ (void)fetchRecordsWithType:(NSString *)recordType
           completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *records, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    NSPredicate *truePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];

    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:recordType
                                               predicate:truePredicate];

    CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = @[@"Entry"];

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {

        [results addObject:record]; };

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *error) {

        [self retrieveNextBatchOfQueryFromCursor:cursor
                                         results:results
                                           error:error
                               completionHandler:completionHandler]; };

    [[self CloudKitContainer].privateCloudDatabase addOperation:queryOperation]; }


+ (void)retrieveNextBatchOfQueryFromCursor:(CKQueryCursor *)cursor
                                   results:(NSMutableArray *)results
                                     error:(NSError *)error
                         completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *records, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    // CloudKit apparently has query limit

    if (cursor != nil
        && !error) {

        CKQueryOperation *nextOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithCursor:cursor];

        nextOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {

            [results addObject:record]; };

        nextOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *error) {

            [self retrieveNextBatchOfQueryFromCursor:cursor
                                             results:results
                                               error:error
                                   completionHandler:completionHandler]; };

        [[self CloudKitContainer].privateCloudDatabase addOperation:nextOperation]; }

    else {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            completionHandler(results, error); }); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of running it inside a function with a completion handler that won't stop until all records are fetched. This can be re-used by different different view controllers across the app.

**Query**

```
func cloudKitLoadRecords(result: (objects: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void){

    // predicate
    var predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    // query
    let cloudKitQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "ClassName", predicate: predicate)

    // records to store
    var records = [CKRecord]()

    //operation basis
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    // recurrent operations function
    var recurrentOperationsCounter = 101
    func recurrentOperations(cursor: CKQueryCursor?){
        let recurrentOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
        recurrentOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
            print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - fetch \(recurrentOperationsCounter++)")
            records.append(record)
        }
        recurrentOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - error - \(error)")
                result(objects: nil, error: error)
            }
            else
            {
                if cursor != nil
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - records \(records.count) - cursor \(cursor!.description)")
                    recurrentOperations(cursor!)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - recurrentOperations - records \(records.count) - cursor nil - done")
                    result(objects: records, error: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        publicDatabase.addOperation(recurrentOperation)
    }

    // initial operation
    var initialOperationCounter = 1
    let initialOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: cloudKitQuery)
    initialOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - fetch \(initialOperationCounter++)")
        records.append(record)
    }
    initialOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - error - \(error)")
            result(objects: nil, error: error)
        }
        else
        {
            if cursor != nil
            {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - records \(records.count) - cursor \(cursor!.description)")
                recurrentOperations(cursor!)
            }
            else
            {
                print("-> cloudKitLoadRecords - initialOperation - records \(records.count) - cursor nil - done")
                result(objects: records, error: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    publicDatabase.addOperation(initialOperation)
}
```

**Usage**

```
cloudKitLoadRecords() { (queryObjects, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if error != nil
                {
                    // handle error
                }
                else
                {
                    // clean objects array if you need to
                    self.objects.removeAll()

                    if queryObjects!.count == 0
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        // attach found objects to your object array
                        self.objects = queryObjects!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example for Swift:

```
func fetchServices(completion: ErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var records = [CKRecord]()

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Service", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
        records.append(record)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
        self.fetchServices(with: cursor, error: error, records: records, completion: completion)
    }

    database.add(queryOperation)
}

private func fetchServices(with cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: Swift.Error?, records: [CKRecord], completion: ErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var currentRecords = records

    if let cursor = cursor, error == nil {

        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            currentRecords.append(record)
        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            self.fetchServices(with: cursor, error: error, records: currentRecords, completion: completion)
        }

        database.add(queryOperation)

    } else {
        parseAndSaveServices(with: records, completion: completion)
    }
}
```