# swift load all record from cloud kit avoiding limit result

Tags: swift

guys need help i can't find something similar online even setting the limit result to a fixed value still doesn't work no matter what i always get 100 record max i need all the records in my database right now is 377 record and will be way more probably 10k but this process will only run once could someone help me catch all the record from the database avoiding the 100 limit please

i added the cursor as you suggested and now i have an idea but now it loads 200 results not the total any tip please

```
 if foodList.count == 0{
        loadingView.hidden = false
        loadMainDatabaseActivity.startAnimating()

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "FoodListDataBase", predicate: predicate)
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        //operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

            if record != nil{
                count++
                foodList.append(record.objectForKey("foodname") as! String)
                categories.append(record.objectForKey("category") as! String)

            }
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor: CKQueryCursor!, error: NSError!) in

            if cursor != nil {
                let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
                newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = operation.recordFetchedBlock
                newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
                newOperation.resultsLimit = 300
                publicDB!.addOperation(newOperation)
                println(count)
            }
            self.loadingView.hidden = true
            self.loadMainDatabaseActivity.stopAnimating()
        }

        publicDB.addOperation(operation)

    }
```

Comment: If the search yields many records, the operation object may deliver a portion of the total results to your blocks immediately, along with a cursor for obtaining the remaining records. If a cursor is provided, use it to initialize and execute a separate CKQueryOperation object when you are ready to process the next batch of results.

Comment: I added this in my querycompletionblock as you said but i now receive 200 result but not the total any tip please thanks                                                   if cursor != nil {
                    let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
                    newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = operation.recordFetchedBlock
                    newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
                    newOperation.resultsLimit = 300
                    publicDB!.addOperation(newOperation)
                    println(count)
                }

Comment: Have you tried removing resulLimit inside closure ? Also put println(count) inside the recordFetchBlock

Comment: I believe println(count) will not be called when the last queryCompletitonBlock is fired. Since the cursor will be nil... So probably you are fetching all records, you just don't see last println.

Comment: thanks guys for all your support here are the updates i tried removing the limits and already had the print(count) within the fetch record but always the count is 200 and i know i don't get the entire result because in my code i add the result to an array to create a custom search and there are results still missing

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more code ? Or make example project ?

Comment: Thanks guys but i was reading about a third party db like parse and i loved it its way much faster i was able to do it with parse but thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was answered in the following post:

[CKQuery from private zone returns only first 100 CKRecords from in CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592964/ckquery-from-private-zone-returns-only-first-100-ckrecords-from-in-cloudkit)

Changing the CKQueryOperationMaximumResults to a larger number.