# CloudKit Query Operation only returns 300 results

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I am currently setting up CloudKit as a replacement to Parse and need to download all of my user records. I currently have around 600 records but I am only receiving 300.

I'm using a custom record zone called "User" rather than the default "Users" record zone as this app will only ever be tied to one appID.

The code I am using is based on the answer to the below question but it's not working for me. It seems that the query operation does not run when the cursor is nil as the print(userArray) is never called. Thanks in advance for your help!

[CKQuery from private zone returns only first 100 CKRecords from in CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592964/ckquery-from-private-zone-returns-only-first-100-ckrecords-from-in-cloudkit)

```
func queryAllUsers() {

    let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = self.createUserObject

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in

        if cursor != nil {
            print("there is more data to fetch")
            let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = self.createUserObject
            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock
            database.addOperation(newOperation)

        } else {

            print(userArray) //Never runs
        }
    }

    database.addOperation(queryOperation)

}

func createUserObject(record: CKRecord) {
    let name = record.objectForKey("Name") as! String!
    let company = record.objectForKey("Company") as! String!
    let dateInductionCompleted = record.objectForKey("DateInductionCompleted") as! NSDate!
    var image = UIImage()

    let imageAsset = record.objectForKey("Image") as! CKAsset!
    if let url = imageAsset.fileURL as NSURL? {
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)
        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        mainQueue.addOperationWithBlock() {
            image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            userArray.append(User(name: name, company: company, image: image, dateInductionCompleted: dateInductionCompleted))
        }
    }
    print(userArray.count)
}
```

**UPDATE**

The question has been answered, it was possibly an inherent bug when using a cursor for large queries. The code now works by using a recursive function, working code below:

```
func queryRecords() {

    let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = populateUserArray

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in

        if cursor != nil {
            print("There is more data to fetch")
            self.fetchRecords(cursor!)
        }
    }
    database.addOperation(queryOperation)
}


func fetchRecords(cursor: CKQueryCursor?) {

    let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
    queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = populateUserArray

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in

        if cursor != nil {
            print("More data to fetch")
            self.fetchRecords(cursor!)

        } else {
            print(userArray)
        }
    }

    database.addOperation(queryOperation)
}

func populateUserArray(record: CKRecord) {

    let name = record.objectForKey("Name") as! String!
    let company = record.objectForKey("Company") as! String!
    let dateInductionCompleted = record.objectForKey("DateInductionCompleted") as! NSDate!
    var image = UIImage()

    let imageAsset = record.objectForKey("Image") as! CKAsset!
    if let url = imageAsset.fileURL as NSURL? {
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)
        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        mainQueue.addOperationWithBlock() {
            image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            userArray.append(User(name: name, company: company, image: image, dateInductionCompleted: dateInductionCompleted))
        }
    }
    print(userArray.count)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try setting:

```
queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
```

This will indicate that your user interaction requires the data.
Otherwise it could happen that de request is ignored completely.

As discussed below the actual answer was that you should not re-use completion blocks. Instead you should create a recursive function for fetching the next records from a cursor. A sample of that can be found at: [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/1bfa936cb46c5a2ca75f080d90a3c02e925b7e56/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDao.swift#L344-344)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this on queryOperation and newOperation but it is still stopping at 300. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I have seen problems with the cursor before when you try to reuse a completion block in a new operation. Here you can see that I have a separate function for a query with a cursor that can be called recursively: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/1bfa936cb46c5a2ca75f080d90a3c02e925b7e56/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDao.swift#L344-344

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!! Did you want to update your answer with that information and I'll mark it as answered. I'll add my working code to my question too.